# adding TinyMCE dynamically to div

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, tinymce

When I initiate a tinymce on a static div it works nicely.
This I am using so the user can post a new post.

Then when the user wants to edit the post which is being displayed from the db through a loop, he can hit edit and a new tinymce instance is attached to the content div. So far so good.

The problem is, when updating the edited post, ajax can't serialise the tinymce editor.

```
 <div id="content_text_<?php echo($id); ?>" class="event-edit-input textarea-content">
     <?php echo($content); ?>
 </div>
```

This is the function being called when the user hits edit:

```
/////// create a tinymce instance and apend it to the given element //////
function create_tinymce(element){
tinymce.init({
    selector: element,
    skin: 'jb',
    content_css : 'css/tinymce-style.css',
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link',
    fontsize_formats: '8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px',
    entity_encoding: 'named'
});
}
```

then the function to post the form:

```
/////// posting the form ////
function post_form(form, script, editor){

tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);

var serialized_form = $("#"+form).serialize();

alert(serialised_form);

}
```

When I alert the serialised form data, everything except the tinymce content shows up.

I don't get it, the only difference from my working setup is, that the latter is static and not being created dynamically.

Can anyone help me out here... ?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: What version of TinyMCE are you using? What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I am using 4.3.12 and am trying safari

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the `triggerSave()` function to the TinyMCE init so that on the editor's change event the underlying field is updated automatically...

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    .
    .
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

This would eliminate the need to do this as you attempt to post the form via AJAX.

UPDATE:  Is your selector a STRING or the DOM Element?  Based on what I see in your code

```
function create_tinymce(element){
tinymce.init({
  selector: element,
  skin: 'jb',
  ...
```

It looks like you are trying to provide a DOM Element (or jQuery wrapped DOM Element).  The selector parameter expects a STRING as documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#selector

If you hard code (as a test) a String does that work?

Comment: Tried that.
Its not that the field doesn't get updated rather that there doesn't seem to be a field altogether.
As I stated in the question, I do have a static form with a tinyMCE div that works perfectly.

Comment: Are your two tinyMCE editors on the same page and active at the same time?

Comment: @Chris Please see my update regarding the `selector` portion of your init.

Comment: @MichaelFromin it is a string i am passing in the function.
And the editor instance is created properly.
The thing is, that when posting the form, the editor does not appear in the serialized data string.

Comment: @Chris any chance you could build an example of this that people could see via the web?  At this point I suspect this is specific to the page you have created.  For example, are you 100% sure the item you are adding is a child element of the `<form>` you want to serialize?  Seeing the HTML in the browser would help people help you debug this issue.